GitVersion 6.0.0 'Property 'tag' not found error
I needed to upgrade to GitVersion 6.0.0-beta.6 for .NET 8 support, but this leads to following exception in my Gitlab CI Build Job: An error occurred:
Could not build the configuration instance because following exception occurred: 'Property 'tag' not found on type 'GitVersion.Configuration.BranchConfiguration'.' Please ensure that the /overrideconfig parameters are correct and the configuration file is in the correct format.
My GitVersion-File is pretty similar to the default configuration of the GitVersion page:
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
branches:
main:
source-branches: [ 'feature', 'integration' ]
regex: ^main|^origin/main$
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag: beta
increment: Minor
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
track-merge-target: false
tracks-release-branches: false
is-release-branch: true
is-mainline: false
integration:
source-branches: [ 'feature', 'integration' ]
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag: alpha
increment: Minor
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
track-merge-target: true
regex: ^integration|^origin/integration$
tracks-release-branches: true
is-release-branch: false
is-mainline: false
release:
mode: ContinuousDelivery
tag: ''
increment: Minor
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
track-merge-target: false
source-branches: [ 'release', 'main' ]
tracks-release-branches: false
is-release-branch: false
is-mainline: true
pre-release-weight: 55000
ignore:
sha: [ ]
Does anyone have an idea, why this exception occurs?

gitversion 6.0.0 made some breaking changes, including renaming tag to label, see https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md:

The configuration properties continuous-delivery-fallback-tag, tag-number-pattern, and tag were renamed to continuous-delivery-fallback-label, label-number-pattern, and label respectively. tag-pre-release-weight and tag-prefix remained as they were as they are referring to a Git tag.

